# Can't create table `cms`.`invoice` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, sql

What did I do wrong in the INVOICE table?

This is the report :

2021-01-25 13:49:23 0x6820 Error in foreign key constraint of table `hmsarea`.`invoice`:

FOREIGN KEY (VISIT_ID)
REFERENCES VISIT(VISIT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_INVOICEAPT FOREIGN KEY (APPOINTMENT_ID)
REFERENCES APPOINTMENT(APPOINTMENT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_INVOICETRT FOREIGN KEY (TREATMENT_ID)
REFERENCES TREATMENT(TREATMENT_ID)
):

```
CREATE TABLE VISIT (
VISIT_ID INT,
PATIENT_ID INT,
VISIT_DATE VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT FK_V1 FOREIGN KEY (DOCTOR_ID)
  REFERENCES DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_V2 FOREIGN KEY (PATIENT_ID)
  REFERENCES PATIENT(PATIENT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT (
APPOINTMENT_ID INT,
APPOINTMENT_DATE VARCHAR(50),
PATIENT_ID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (APPOINTMENT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_APP1 FOREIGN KEY (DOCTOR_ID)
  REFERENCES DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_APP2 FOREIGN KEY (PATIENT_ID)
  REFERENCES PATIENT(PATIENT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TREATMENT (
TREATMENT_ID INT,
TREATMENT_TYPE VARCHAR(100),
PATIENT_ID INT,
TREATMENT_DATE VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (TREATMENT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_TR1 FOREIGN KEY (DOCTOR_ID)
  REFERENCES DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_TR2 FOREIGN KEY (PATIENT_ID)
  REFERENCES PATIENT(PATIENT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
INVOICE_NO INT,
INVOICE_TOTAL DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
INVOICE_DATE VARCHAR(25),
PRESCRIPTION_ID INT,
VISIT_ID INT,
APPOINTMENT_ID INT NULL,
TREATMENT_ID INT NULL,
PATIENT_INT INT,
PATIENT_FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (INVOICE_NO),
CONSTRAINT FK_INVOICE1 FOREIGN KEY (VISIT_ID)
  REFERENCES VISIT(VISIT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_INVOICE2 FOREIGN KEY (APPOINTMENT_ID)
REFERENCES APPOINTMENT(APPOINTMENT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_INVOICE3 FOREIGN KEY (TREATMENT_ID)
REFERENCES TREATMENT(TREATMENT_ID)
);
```

Comment: The reason is the usual inattention...

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69df84bc27ea0aa9f5e21948db90653e)

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'FK_INVOICEVISIT' in the referenced table 'VISIT'

`VISIT.VISIT_ID` is not indexed.

> Key column 'PATIENT_ID' doesn't exist in table

The column name is `PATIENT_INT`.

> All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

`RECEIPT_NO` is defined as NULL explicitly.